# scipy.optimize.fmin_cg function need two callable function f and fprime, how could I extract two function from a function that return both two values?

Tags: python, machine-learning

```
 def linear_regression(theta, X, y, lamb):
    # X(12,1+1)  theta(2,1) y(12,1)
    m = X.shape[0]
    ones = np.ones([m, 1])
    X = np.hstack([ones, X])
    h = X.dot(theta)
    # cost function
    J = 1 / 2 / m * np.sum(np.power(h - y, 2)) + lamb / 2 / m * np.sum(np.power(theta[1:], 2))
    # gradient   X(12,2)  X.T(2,12) (h-y)(12,1)   sum_error(2,1)\
    sum_error = 1 / m * X.T.dot(h - y)
    temp = theta
    temp[0] = 0
    gradient = sum_error + lamb / m * temp
    return J, gradient




def f(theta, X, y, lamb):
    J, gradient = linear_regression(theta, X, y, lamb)
    return J


def fprime(theta, X, y, lamb):
    J, gradient = linear_regression(theta, X, y, lamb)
    return gradient



J, gradient = linear_regression(theta,X,y,1)
# theta need to be a vector not matrix
result = opt.fmin_cg(f, theta, fprime=fprime, args=(X,y,1))
print(result[0])
```

Explain:

1. opt.fmin_cg(f, theta, fprime=fprime, args=(X,y,1))  need a callable function f and fprime
2. f, fprime is the return value of linear_regression(theta, X, y, lamb)
3. It is easy to compute the cost function and gradient in the same function

Question:

1. Is there an easy way to extract two callable function from linear_regression(theta, X, y, lamb)
2. calling J, gradient = linear_regression(theta,X,y,1) and pass to opt.fmin_cg(J, theta, fprime=gradient , args=(X,y,1)) is not work